# How do i create Custom Drop List in WFFM

Tags: wffm, custom-field

How do i create a custom Dropdown for WFFM(Sitecore 8.1), i want to have a MvC drop list which is populated from an external service and showed in forms .

Comment: https://soen.ghost.io/creating-a-custom-field-type-in-wffm-for-sitecore/

Comment: Thats for textbox he needs it for Drop List